# What version of the Star Wars script was Alec Guinness given that he said couldn't stop reading?

Tags: star-wars

I saw Alec Guinness interviewed on the David Letterman show (on Youtube), and he mentioned that he was given the script to Star Wars shortly after he finished filming Murder By Death.

He said the dialog was terrible but that he couldn't stop reading the script, which caused him to get interested in the project.

What version of the Star Wars script was Alec Guinness reading?

I'm asking because he might have read an early draft of the Star Wars script that didn't resemble the final film.

Comment: I think this will fall under off-topic here. finding a script/recommendations are considered off-topic because they were huge magnets to attract unnecessary and spammy posts  in the past.

Comment: *Murder by Death* was released Aug 1976, the [third draft](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Star_Wars:_From_The_Adventures_of_Luke_Starkiller) of *Star Wars* was completed in Aug 1975. It could've been that, or it could've (more likely IMO) been the final script. Note that's not the same as what was produced, due to on-set improvisation and changes.

Comment: Although this isn't what you asked for, Dark Horse put together ideas from some of the early rough drafts and released a comic titled, The Star Wars. The story itself doesn't transition very well, but it has unique artwork based on Ralph McQuarrie's early designs and it gives a lot of insight on how different it could of been https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Star_Wars

Comment: @Vishwa It doesn't really, no. But to clarify that, I removed the sentence about wanting to read the same draft.